# doctrine:generate:entity で　PDOException　が発生してしまう

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

symfony2　でモデルを作成しようとしたところ、PDOExceptionが発生してしまいます

```
 The Entity shortcut name:QuartetBlogBundle:Post
```

→　Enter すると、下記エラーが発生

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException] 
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused 

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException] 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

config.yml の　unix_socket　は以下のようになっています

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock　//php.ini に同じ
```

こちら、何か設定ミスがありますでしょうか。
または上記以外で　doctrine:generate:entity　が出来れば、そのやり方を教えてほしいです。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/36373 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

> An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

というエラーなので、MySQLに接続できていないのが原因なんだと思います。

`%database_host%`の値が`127.0.0.1`になっていたりしませんか？
MySQL側に`skip-networking`が設定されていると`127.0.0.1`で接続できません。(TCPコネクションを拒否しているので。）
その場合は`localhost`を指定してと接続出来るかと思います(Unixドメインソケットでの接続になるので)

Symfonyの問題ではなくMySQLの設定の問題なのでもう一度設定を見なおしてみるといいと思います。

参考記事: http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/b00b72c5c95aac573b71#comment-e9db50fff9bffa1dd6f8